# Generate javadoc for classes that have non-ascii charaters in their names

Tags: encoding, javadoc, gradle

Some of the classes in our code base have Unicode (Danish) characters in their names. It works fine for compilation and deployment, but it failed when generating Javadoc complaining about wrong characters in the java sources. We are using Gradle to build our code base and the following options actually solved the problem with wrong characters:

```
  javadoc {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
  }
```

But that still fails on finding classes that have non-ASCII characters in their names:

```
javadoc: error - File not found: "E:\Work\source\common\my-integration\src\main\java\my\company\vehicle\common\K├©ret├©jListeHentValidationHelper.java"
```

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Non-ASCII characters in file names are always a problem. I suppose there is some encoding used for file names on disk, and another one by Java trying to access them. Could setting the system default encoding help?

Comment: I would save myself trouble and switch to ASCII file names:)

Comment: If I was to decide which characters to use in Java class names, then of course I would never used anything else than ASCII, but it's more or less comes from client requirements.

Comment: Why downvote? Is there any problem with the question?